# Mysql console backup import fails in correct directory with correct password

Tags: mysql, sql, database, console, command-line-interface

I use Ubuntu server 16.04 (xenial) with Mysql 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20 (x86_64) with EditLine wrapper.

I have a Wordpress site `/var/www/html/${domain}/` which I've duplicated with `cp` into `/var/www/html/test/` and changed `wp-config.php` accordingly.

I have **exported** a DB backup of `${domain}` this way:

```
mysqldump -u root -p"${rps}" "${domain}" > /var/www/html/test.sql
```

This `test.sql` file weighs 22mbs, just like a regular sql backup of the site, so the operation seems to be successful.

I've also logged into the **mysql console** and created an authorized, all-privileged DB user and instance, for the `test` site:

```
CREATE user "test"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${sps}";
CREATE database test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;
```

<sub>Note: `rps` and `sps` stand for "(mysql) root password" and "(mysql) site password". Echoing both show correct values.</sub>

I then exited back to the Ubuntu console.

---

### So far so good, but here's the problem:

While in `/var/www/html/` I tried to **import** my `test.sql` file into it's corresponding DB instance:

```
mysql -u test -p"${sps}" < test.sql
```

And yet, my import operation fails.

I also tried this import syntax:

```
mysql -u test -p"${sps}" test < test.sql
```

Both import operations failed with the exact same error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

### My question

Why would I be denied access when I seem to use the correct password?

I emphasis that I've double checked and ensured that `${sps}` holds the correct password by `echo ${sps}`.

### Update_1

Even though this session includes the main parts of the code, [you can view the entire code here](https://github.com/benqzq/dwa/blob/master/dwa.sh).

### Update_2 --- milestone

It seems that the problem is due to the variable not being expanded when the user is being created:

```
CREATE user "test"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "${sps}";
```

I've confirmed this when manually creating a user with a password. Passwords fromo variables just won't count.

Comment: Is the `sps` password specifically the MySQL password for the MySQL user `test`? I would still troubleshoot this as an MySQL authorization error; it doesn't seem to be related to your script.

Comment: Indeed @tripleee this is the password of that particular mysql user `test`.

Comment: I have double checked about 5 times this is the correct password, and even tried to use it manually and even copying it from a text editor instead of MS word but still, each time it fails, even in a simple `mysql -u test p[MY_PASSWORD]`.

Comment: That seems to lack a dash. I don't understand what MS Word has with anything to do but it sounds like something you should try to factor out. Don't answer here, but does the password contain non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Did you try *FLUSH PRIVILEGES* after granting the user access to DB?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help then if I recall correctly. Anyway, please see my answer and link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it happens is because the variable ${sps} didn't get expanded inside the Mysql shell; Mysql shell isn't bash and doesn't include this behavior of variable expansion (in this case, of the type variable substitution).

[See more data and a way to cope with this here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410182/variable-wont-get-expanded-when-inside-mysql-shell?noredirect=1#comment734787_410182).